# IntelliJ Drools plugin - keyword in import statement

Tags: intellij-idea, drools

I have problem with Jboss Drools plugin in IntelliJ. When I try to import java class in .drl file (java class is in package called 'action') IntelliJ shows error: "'*' or JAVA_IDENTIFIER expected, got 'action'". 'action' is a keyword in Drools.

[image: Problem screenshot]

Same thing in Eclipse works well.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I will be very grateful for answer.

Regards,
KJ

Comment: Enclosing the keywort `action` in backticks, which should, according to the Drools manual, make a keyword usable as a plain identifier, does not work. So, it seems, that the Intellij plugin has two bugs. - I can't think of anything else but renaming "action".

Comment: Thanks for answer. Unfortunately can't rename package. Have to go back to Eclipse. You're right, it is a bug. I've just found it and also commented there: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-108223